# Do links from every page on my main domain to subdomain hurt SEO?

Tags: seo, subdomain, links

I have a WordPress website (eg example.com) which is basically a blog with weekly educational posts about a specific subject. I also have a subdomain (eg courses.example.com) which offers online courses about the exact topics I write about in my blog.

I want to put a link (courses.example.com) on my every blog post on my main example.com site. Will it hurt my SEO for every one of my posts on example.com to link to the courses.example.com?

If yes, is there any recommendation?

Comment: Just to clarify, all I want is my visitors know that there are online courses related to these topics. I'm not looking for any DA or PA improvements.

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't hurt your website. Just make sure your links are natural (i.e. they belong in the content) and try to use natural-looking anchor text and you'll be fine - this is an internal link and Google knows this is the correct usage for them.